# PHP wierd, locally works but server does not

Tags: session-variables, php

I'm working on this web page using PHP. I'm testing local using easyphp version: 5.3.9
I did a usual sign in, sign out functionality. When I test locally, works just as expected. But when I upload it to a godaddy hosting service via FTP, it starts to do wierd things.

- The session variables are not working correctly, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work! 
  The sign in connection and validation on db is working fine! but is when reading SESSION variables from another file that fails.

What could it be? php version? but I'm just using simple $_SESSION['name'] variables. Bug? please help!

This is what I have already tried:

- Using other browsers.
- Re upload the source (many times)
- Clearing cache, cookies etc..
- Testing step by step, but like i said it works fine hosting the web page locally.

One last thing that it might be important is that the db is hosted on a server (which is not my local pc ofc) And the connection to this db is working fine on both scenarios.

This is my code:

landing.php (in case you want to know xD):

```
<div class="xxx">Log in</div>
    <div class="xxx">
        <form class="xxxx" method="post" action="Bean.php">
            <input type="hidden" value="login" name="oper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="mail"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass"/>
            <input type="submit" value="LOG IN!" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Bean.php

```
if (!isset ($_COOKIE[ini_get('name')])) {
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_name('name');
session_start();
}
if($oper=="login")
{
$user=$cws->VerifyUser($_POST['mail'],$_POST['pass']);//$cws is a class that connects to the server with the db via WS
if(strlen($user->body->mail)>5)//this is because if the user is not found it returns blank or '@.'
{
    $_SESSION['session_mail']=$user->body->mail;
    $_SESSION['session_name']=$user->body->name;
    $_SESSION['session_miniPicture']=$user->body->miniPicture;
    $_SESSION['session_on']=true;
    //This are the variables I can't read later!

    echo("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >                                             location.replace(\"../home.php\");
                                </script>");
}
else{
    echo("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >
                                    alert(\"E-mail or password incorrect \");                                   location.replace(\"../landing.php\");
                                </script>");
  }

}
```

home.php:

```
if (!isset ($_COOKIE[ini_get('name')])) {
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_name('name');
session_start();
}
//In this check, the variable $_SESSION['session_on'] is NOT set! WHY???
if(!isset($_SESSION['session_on']) || $_SESSION['session_on']==false)
{
   echo("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >
                                        location.replace(\"landing.php\");
                                        </script>");

}
echo ( "mail: ".$_SESSION['session_mail']."<br/>"); // for debug
echo ( "name: ".$_SESSION['session_name']."<br/>"); // for debug
echo ( "on: ".$_SESSION['session_on']."<br/>"); // for debug

 Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['session_name']; ?> &nbsp;- <a href="signout.php">Sign out</a>
```

signout.php:

```
if (!isset ($_COOKIE[ini_get('name')])) {
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_name('name');
session_start();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['session_on']) && $_SESSION['session_on']==true)
{
  $_SESSION['session_on']=false;
  echo("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >

                                       location.replace(\"landing.php\");
                                    </script>");

}
```

Please help! should I contact godaddy support? is this related to php version? what could it be? thank you

Alejandro Casas

Comment: Using other browsers doesn't really change anything. The PHP script is executed server side, PHP doesn't care about what browser you are using, it cares about the request only.

Comment: What's with the `ini_get('name')` business? Why are you checking for a cookie before initialising the session?

Comment: Well I was getting warnings saying that the session was already started, so I found this solution around. Is this wrong? Thank you both for your response.

Comment: Do you use subfolders and/or frames?

Comment: @Alejandro Do you control your code or not? Simply use `session_start()` once. You can also generally test if the session has started using `isset($_SESSION)`

Comment: Hello, Yes I use subfolders. The Bean.php is inside a subfolder. I thought that would not change anything.

Comment: @Phil Well I'm learning here, so I guess this is how the process works, I will change it and test, and post back. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see - you problem is the following:

You are starting a session only if there is no session cookie. But if you logout, your session and your cookie is not destroyed. Situation is this. You write something in the session in File1.php and want to read it in File2.php. But in File2.php the session is never initiated, because you have a session cookie. You will have to start a session in any file, so remove the $_COOKIE condition from you code.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_name('name');
session_start();
```

Comment: Hi, I'm testing this, I will answer in a minute! thank you for your help

Comment: hi again, I changed this if (!isset ($_COOKIE[ini_get('name')])) {
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
    session_name('name');
    session_start(); } ----- FOR THIS: if (!isset ($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();

} BUT I'm having the same results.

Comment: And if you remove the condition completely?

Comment: Would the subfoldes be the ones doing something wrong? because the SESSION variables are set inside a subfolder.

Comment: Do you get any error messages about the session already startet?

Comment: yes Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: Ok, then you will have to find out, where the session was started. The problem might be (only a guess), that you session was started with a wrong path (subfolder) or a wrong session name.